# Angular2 can't resolve 'angular2-google-maps' error Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

When I try to build the project during some process it hangs up with an error

```
ERROR in multi vendor

    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular2-google-maps' in 'path_to_project'
     @ multi vendor
```

I also get these as warnings. I don't understand exactly what is the problem and where I need to look at.

```
WARNING in ./~/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fsevents' in 'page_to_project\node_modules\chokidar\lib'
 @ ./~/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js 7:17-36
 @ ./~/chokidar/index.js
 @ ./~/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
 @ ./~/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
 @ ./~/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node ^\.\/.*$
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeMainTemplate.runtime.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeMainTemplatePlugin.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin.js
 @ ./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js
 @ ./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js
 @ multi vendor

WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js
78:29 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/bin-wrapper/index.js
5:34 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

Resolve part in webpack.dist.conf looks like this

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
      'scripts',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    packageMains: ['angular2-google-maps'],
    externals: {
      "window":"window"
    },
    extensions: [
      '',
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.jsx',
      '.ts'
    ]
  },
```